# Hybris use Employee to login in storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

In Hybris, Employees extend from User, however, I can't use a Employee to login in storefront. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly ... at least not without some very major customisation.  The storefront logic is based around the Customer type, which is another subtype of User.  There are multiple places in the standard logic where methods expect a Customer rather than a User or Employee.

On the other hand, it depends what exactly you are trying to achieve?  There is a standard module called the Assisted Service Module (ASM) that allows an Employee with the correct permissions (typically a customer service representative) to login and select a Customer to emulate.  They then browse/use the website as that Customer, and can see what that customer would see.

Comment: I need to create a storefront that works similar to Backoffice, only logged employees can use this page. Can I use ASM in order to achieve something  similar?

Comment: Not really ... ASM is for customer service employees to assist customers on the standard storefront, as if they were the customer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to login using an Employee account, you have to override this bean implementation

```
<security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            username-parameter="j_username" 
            password-parameter="j_password" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
              />
```

In ootb implementation,  `loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler` calls `StorefrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and this class needs a customer to run properly (for example it calls `getCustomerFacade().loginSuccess();`)

Fix `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and you should be able to connect as Employee.